# iFrames Vs Web Services for embedding Jasper Reports

Tags: web-services, iframe, jasperserver

I am using the community edition 5.2 for jasper server  and wish to embed reports into my web application. What is a better way to achieve this considering I will be using the functionality offered by the community edition.

Since the community edition is non interactive, I do not want to expose the clients to report repositories but want them to be able to view reports, filter reports and download them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you could use: http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/php-client
to run/fetch reports. 
How I would do it:

```
View a report: Run report with html output -> save output to /tmp/abcd/ -> embedd it into your webapp.
```

```
Download: Run report with pdf output, save it to /tmp/abce/ -> provide it as download
```

```
Filter: List all items in a sudirectory -> Filter it with php / JavaScript
```

If you just got precompiled report. Things get even easier.